# Manipulate highlighted text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, text

HI,
I'm trying to develop some code in Javascript that adds highlighted text to a class. What I want to achieve with this is the ability of text highlighting with a custom color.

I want it to kind of look like the following:

```
window.getSelected = "<span class=\"highlighted\">" + window.getSelected + "</span>"
```

after the above code is executed the selected text's background is surrounded by span tags.

thanks,

fbr

Comment: Do you mean text highlighting when by marking some text ion the page or just give text inside a certain class a certain background color?

Comment: I want to allow users to highlight by marking text with the mouse. Something like:
window.getSelected = <span class="highlighted"> window.getSelected </span>

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into Range Objects, there is a good summary here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html

Browser compatibility will be an issue, but basically, you can get the current selection in the way you suggest, then convert it into a Range, and use the methods of the Range object to find and split the existing DOM nodes, and insert your own `<span>` tag containing the selected text.

It's not entirely trivial, and involves getting into serious DOM manipulation, but it's a rewarding subject to get your head around. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

excuse my english, do you mean adding a class to a text?

```js
function changeClass (elementID, newClass) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
    element.setAttribute("class", newClass); // This is for good browsers
    element.setAttribute("className", newClass); //For IE<
}
```

leave all lines, its harmless if you do that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about styling native selections, use `::selection` and `::-moz-selection` in CSS.

```
::selection {
  color: ...;
  background-color: ...;
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: ...;
  background-color: ...;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to highlight an arbitrary element with a class:

### CSS

```
.highlighted {
  color: ...;
  background-color: ...;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
yourElement.className = "highlighted";
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the [jQuery framework](http://jquery.com/) you can try with the following code:

```
var your_color = 'yellow';
$('.your-class').css('background-color', your_color);
```

If you're not using it I highly suggest you start; it makes things a lot easier, it's very stable and it's used by many popular websites including google and stack overflow itself.

Comment: I've used jQuery... But my question remains unanswered. I'm building an eBook reader with HTML/JAvascript and CSS, and I want to allow users to highlight text. They highlight text with the mouse, pick a color and the selected text's background turns into the color the user picked.